# Symfony2, PHP, sending multidimensional array with Curl without http_build_query

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, curl, multidimensional-array

I need to send a complex array to an API, that only excepts an array as the body. It works fine wit ha simple array. But when I send a multidimentional array, for example:

```
    array (size=44)
      'id' => int 2707
      'model' => string 'test55' (length=6)
      'admin_title' => string 'test55' (length=6)
      'status' => boolean true
      'special' => boolean false
      'created_at' => 
        array (size=3)
          'date' => string '2016-02-29 09:34:12' (length=19)
          'timezone_type' => int 3
          'timezone' => string 'Europe/Paris' (length=12)
      'updated_at' => 
        array (size=3)
          'date' => string '2016-02-29 13:42:51' (length=19)
          'timezone_type' => int 3
          'timezone' => string 'Europe/Paris' (length=12)
      ...
```

I get error:

```
Array to string conversion.
```

This is my curl setup:

```
$ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'url');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/x-www-form-urlencoded, Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded')); // Assuming you're requesting JSON
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $decoded);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        $result = json_decode($response, true);
        var_dump($result);
        curl_close($ch);
        die;
```

If i use hhtp_build_query it creates a single string as data, and it is not accepted by the application... What can I do?

Comment: I assume `$decoded` is your array? Http is "string-based", you can't just pass an array and hope it works. Does the endpoint provide some kind of documentation about what type of content they are requesting? (xml, json etc?)

Comment: They are requesting an array. And yes $decode is my multidimentional array. If i send a simple array it works, multidimentional array doesnt.

Comment: not an answer to your question, but use [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) for all your api stuff, its so much easier.

Comment: As a note: Correct your `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` value. Your array should have one entry per header, not a single entry with multiple headers

Comment: What does the handling side (API) look like? Apparently it's trying to parse one of your arrays as a string. But without seeing it, it's hard to tell where it goes wrong.